# complicated case of css active works and almost in IE, too (jsfiddle inside)

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, hover

I'm trying to make a button comprised of several layers. The final layer should be the clickable layer and a click should control the color of a previous layer.

This works in all 4 major browsers except for IE and "active". How do I get this to work in IE?

jsfiddle over here -> http://jsfiddle.net/4vaY6/197/

I'm doing this because I want the whole area to be clickable, it should not have blind spots.

```
<div class = "div1">
    <div class = "div2">        
    </div>
</div>

.div2
{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-color: black;
}

.div1
{
position: absolute;
width: 350px;
height: 100px;
}
.div1:hover .div2 {background-color:yellow;}        
.div1:active .div2 {background-color: grey;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html:

> IE 8-10 (and maybe older ones, too) have a slight bug: clicking the mouse down on a nested element does not trigger :active.

It is even worse with IE7.

You could use JavaScript to simulate the :active behaviour:

Replace

```
.div1:hover .div2 {background-color:yellow;}        
.div1:active .div2 {background-color: grey;}
```

with

```
.hover {background-color: yellow;}
.active {background-color: grey;}
```

And add the following (if you use jQuery):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.div1').hover(function(){
    $('.div2').toggleClass('hover');
});

$('.div1').mousedown(function(){
    $('.div2').addClass('active');
}).mouseup(function(){
    $('.div2').removeClass('active');
});
</script>
```

Or if you use MooTools:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$$('.div1').addEvents({
    'mouseenter': function() { $$('.div2').addClass('hover'); },
    'mouseleave': function() { $$('.div2').removeClass('hover'); },
    'mousedown': function() { $$('.div2').addClass('active'); },
    'mouseup': function() { $$('.div2').removeClass('active'); },
});
</script>
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4vaY6/201/

Comment: hi, thank you. I can see that it works, but I can not reproduce the jsfiddle. Does the script need to be at a special place? I've put in in the head between script tags. Do I need to remove a double $? I have jquery-1.9.0.min.js included and copied the code directly from jfiddle.

Comment: @wubbewubbewubbe Yeah the jsFiddle uses the MooTools framework, you should copy the jQuery code from my answer.

Comment: thanks, it's working. Had to put it between jQuery(document).ready(function(){ ... });